# How to identify applications and DLL which are slowing the File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, dll, windows-11

My PC is usually very fast with NVMe SSD and latest hardware, but File Explorer is really slow in my case. Even small operations like Renaming a file or navigation can take 0.5-1s and sometimes even more. The issue was not there in the beginning but have worsen over the time.

I suspect it's the lot of Software I use. Unfortunately, it's hard for me to uninstall dozens of software to find the culprit.

Is it possible to upload DLL by publishers who are hooking into the File Explorer one-by-one? It will be faster to find the culprit then. I can also later just restart the PC normally with all the programs without having to re-install dozen of software.

Any other solutions are also appreciated

Comment: If File Explorer is not running properly or hanging, it is probably a shell extension issue. This is normally a needle in a haystack issue to solve. I usually do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Comment: To verify if add-ons are the problem, boot in Safe mode. This mode should disable all third-party add-ons.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this but for me personally, they are all sysinternal tools.  Autoruns will allow you to see what is loaded in the explorer (and disable it).. but I myself like to use the process explorer.  I set the lower pane to DLLs, select the explorer, and sort by path.  The process monitor can tell you exactly what the explorer is doing during your timeout but it is a bit of a learning curve as the filters take a bit to figure out.

Comment: @harrymc Yes. File explorer is very fast in a Safe mode. How do I know which of the 3rd party add on is making it slow?

Comment: @John It seems like a 3rd party software issue. Are you sure repair install with help? I recently upgraded from Win 10 to Win 11. It didn't help at all.

Comment: I would try a repair install.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Answer (score 1):

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for this.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system boot or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be uninstalled.

Comment: Is it possible to stop them directly without having to disable and restart?

Comment: I disabled every single setting there (except driver and MS related services). Didn't seem to solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: Try [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html). If nothing is fixed, do a [Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). The links above are for Windows 10, but should apply also to Windows 11 with small adjustments.